# How to interpret data type size and its alignment?

Tags: c, linux, types, memory-alignment

I have a question regarding size/alignment of `double` type in linux/gcc.

On [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment), it's written:

> A double (eight bytes) will be 8-byte aligned on Windows and 4-byte
>   aligned on Linux (8-byte with -malign-double compile time option).

I understand that how an 8 byte data type is 8-byte aligned is stored in memory.

so if we have

```
struct foo {
    double d1;
    double d2;
};
```

I know that the size of this structure would be 16 bytes. But what will be the alignment?

Secondly, how can we visualize 8-byte size with 4-byte alignment?

As an example:

```
int a[2];
```

In the above case, `a[0]` will be Offset = 0 and `a[1]` will be at Offset =32.

But how will it be placed for `double` type in Linux (4 byte alignment)? E.g.

```
double d[2];
```

`d[0]` will of course be at Offset = 0. `d[1]` should be at Offset=64, but the alignment information says that `double` is 4-byte aligned. Maybe I'm missing some point here.

Comment: What about writing a test program printing out sizes and addresses?

Comment: "I know that the size of this structure would be 16 bytes" - Wrong assumption.. please provide a reference to the standard. And the Wikipedia statement is either wrong or incompletely cited.

Comment: The wikipedia quote is very specific to a compilation option (`-malign-double`).  In practice, without such specific compilation options, alignment is more usually a multiple of the size, not a fraction of it.

Comment: Once you receive a good answer, what do you want to do with it?  Why is know alignment important for you?

Comment: 4 byte alignment means that the start address could be a multiple of 4 (like 0x10004), not that it stores a `double` in 4 bytes.

Comment: @chux: I want to know all details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Short answer

Alignment is dependent on implementation and platform. For gcc, you can inquire about an object's alignment by `__alignof__` C extension keyword([gcc 5.4.0 doc](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-5.4.0/gcc/Alignment.html#Alignment)), just like using `sizeof` operator to inquire about an object's size.

---

### Long answer

**Q1. What will be the alignment of `struct foo { double d1; double d2; }`?**

Following example code shows that the alignment of the `struct` in question differs between 64-bit and 32-bit platform. (Tested with gcc 5.4.0)

```
$ cat main.c
#include <stdio.h>

struct foo {
    double d1;
    double d2;
};

int main()
{
    struct foo s_foo[2];
    printf("%d\n", (int)__alignof__(struct foo));
    printf("%p\n", &s_foo[0]);
    printf("%p\n", &s_foo[1]);
}
$ gcc -m64 -o main main.c
$ ./main
8
0x7fff54213ba0
0x7fff54213bb0
$ gcc -m32 -o main main.c
$ ./main
4
0xffb5239c   # 4-byte aligned
0xffb523ac   # 4-byte aligned
$ gcc -m32 -malign-double -o main main.c
$ ./main
8
0xffb398b8
0xffb398c8
```

You can check that `struct dd` is 4-byte aligned for 32-bit, but 8-byte aligned when compiled with `-malign-double` or when compiled for 64-bit.

**Q2. How can we visualize 8-byte size with 4-byte alignment?**

Following example shows such behavior. The `double` type member `d1` of `struct foo` is 8 bytes in size but it's 4-byte aligned.

```
$ cat main.c
#include <stdio.h>

struct foo {
    double d1;
    double d2;
};

int main()
{
    struct foo s_foo[2];
    printf("%d\n", (int)sizeof(s_foo[0].d1));
    printf("%d\n", (int)__alignof__(s_foo[0].d1));
    printf("%p\n", &s_foo[0].d1);
}
$ gcc -m32 -o main main.c
$ ./main
8
4
0xffeca1dc
```

Comment: Thanks for such a detailed answer! I got it.